# The exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError thrown when invoking Azure storage related java API

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, azure, maven, netty

Leave thread here for others who might run into same issues.

---

I'm trying to reading `blob` from Azure `container` by code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String connectStr = "it's a workable connection string...";
    // Create a BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder().connectionString(connectStr).buildClient();
    String containerName = "eugenecontainer";
    BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    for (BlobItem blobItem: blobContainerClient.listBlobs()){
        System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
    }
}
```

However, when it executes `blobContainerClient.listBlobs()`, exception as following throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.config()Lio/netty/bootstrap/BootstrapConfig;
```

I'm using `maven` as the build tool.

What happens here?

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the solution and it's about the `maven` dependency conflict. More than one dependencies depend on `netty` in different versions.

I have added both `aws` and `azure` dependency in maven like below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.327</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
  <version>12.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

By using maven tool `mvn dependency:tree`, I got output as following:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kinesisvideo:jar:1.11.327:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.17.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.azure:azure-storage-common:jar:12.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.42.Final:compile
[INFO] |        +- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |        |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |        |  |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.39.Final:compile
[INFO] |        |  \- io.projectreactor.addons:reactor-pool:jar:0.1.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.azure:azure-core-test:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |           \- io.projectreactor:reactor-test:jar:3.3.0.RELEASE:compile
```

As we can see, `azure` and `aws` did depend on `netty` and the version of `netty` is different. So the question is about solving the conflict.

As per introduciton from [maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html),

> Since Maven resolves dependencies transitively, it is possible for
>   unwanted dependencies to be included in your project's classpath. For
>   example, a certain older jar may have security issues or be
>   incompatible with the Java version you're using. To address this,
>   Maven allows you to exclude specific dependencies. Exclusions are set
>   on a specific dependency in your POM, and are targeted at a specific
>   groupId and artifactId. When you build your project, that artifact
>   will not be added to your project's classpath by way of the dependency
>   in which the exclusion was declared.

We need to exclude `netty` 4.1.17 so that it won't be added to project's classpath and set `netty` to `azure` explicitly.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.327</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>*</artifactId>
          <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
      <version>12.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.42.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

By adding above dependencies to `pom.xml`, the `azure` works fine then.

Comment: If a jar is already present on the classpath because it is provided by the server at runtime, just tell maven the artifact is provided.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring boot dependencies as mentioned below, please exclude the azure-core-http-netty and add new individual dependency for azure-core-http-okhttp as follows.

```html
<dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter-storage</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
                      <artifactId>azure-core-http-netty</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
               <artifactId>azure-core-http-okhttp</artifactId>
               <version>1.2.1</version>
           </dependency>
```